# ACF if / else checkbox

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Hi I've got this code that's looking to see if a checkbox is ticked in a custom post type and then displaying the relevant link

```
<?php
 if(in_array("Yes", get_field('news__item--external') )){
?>
  <a href="<?php echo the_field('news__item--external-url'); ?>" class="more icon--chev">View full article</a>
  <?
  }
  ?>
```

I want to add an else statement to it to provide a different result if no link. 
Doing this:

```
<?php
 if(in_array("Yes", get_field('news__item--external') )){
?>
  <a href="<?php echo the_field('news__item--external-url'); ?>" class="more icon--chev">View full article</a>
  <?
  } else {
  <a href="home.php">Home</a>
  }
  ?>
```

Gives me a parse error. How can I include the else statment?

Thanks

Comment: [you have to close php before outputting html](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small fix for you :)

```
<?php
  if( in_array( "Yes", get_field( 'news__item--external' ) ) ) {
?>
    <a href="<?php echo the_field('news__item--external-url'); ?>" class="more icon--chev">View full article</a>
<? } else { ?>
    <a href="home.php">Home</a>
<?php } ?>
```

The code to fix was:

```
<php } else { <a href="home.php">Home</a>   } ?>
```

You was missing the end php tag from the { after else then the opening php tag before the a tag. Final bit was open php tag after the a tag.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and explain what the small fix was and why this may solve the posters problem?

Comment: Added more info.